# Injective function $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that $f(x)=x^3-2x$ is injective from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. Here is my attempt:

Let $p/q$ and $r/s$ be in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(p/q)=f(r/s)$.

$$\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=f\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)&\Leftrightarrow\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^3-2\frac{p}{q}=\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^3-2\frac{r}{s}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^3-\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^3-2\left(\frac{p}{q}-\frac{r}{s}\right)=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow\left(\frac{p}{q}-\frac{r}{s}\right)\left(\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2+\frac{p}{q}\frac{r}{s}+\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^2\right)-2\left(\frac{p}{q}-\frac{r}{s}\right)=0\\
&\Leftrightarrow\left(\frac{p}{q}-\frac{r}{s}\right)\left(\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2+\frac{p}{q}\frac{r}{s}+\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^2-2\right)=0\\
\end{align*}$$

$$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{r}{s}\text{ or }\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2+\frac{p}{q}\frac{r}{s}+\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^2=2$$

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2+\frac{p}{q}\frac{r}{s}+\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^2=2&\Leftrightarrow\left(\frac{p}{q}+\frac{r}{s}\right)^2-\frac{p}{q}\frac{r}{s}=2
\end{align*}$$
I know that there should be a problem in the last equality, i.e that it should not hold, but I do not know how to go about proving it. I scarcely have experience with such problems using rational numbers, I just know that we represent them by a fraction of two integers (my number theory is bad). Any hint is much appreciated!

Comment: Only a thought - maybe useful? Consider that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$. The definition of $f$ extends to $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and if you can prove it is monotonous over that domain, you're home.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Except it's not mononone on $\mathbb R$ :)

Comment: @Wojowu damn :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplying the second to last equality by $q^2s^2$ gives that $a^2+ab+b^2=2c^2$ for some integers $a,b,c$ with $c>0$. We wish to show this is impossible. At this point we can pretty much forget about $p,q,r,s$.

To show impossibility of $a^2+ab+b^2=2c^2$, assume a solution exists, and pick a solution with $c>0$ as small as possible. Try showing $a,b,c$ are all even and derive a contradiction from there.